# Insert into SQL Server stored procedure to be a command in vb.net 2003

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net, stored-procedures, datagrid

I have a stored procedure in SQL Server that inserts data into tables.

Any ideas on how to make it a SQL command in vb.net 2003 using datagrid?

Comment: sql server enterprise manager is the one im using and vb.net 2003 with a 1.0 and 2.0 .net framework i think.

Comment: What is your app? Winforms? ASP.NET? WPF? Silverlight? Also: why aren't you just calling the stored procedure (seeing that it already exists....)

Comment: VB.NET 2003 datagrid on a windows form. i dont know how to call a stored procedure on a sql in vb.net 2003 thats why im asking some ideas on how to

Comment: Do you want to create sql command for the store procedure?

Comment: @GLOIERTECH. yes sir that was really what i want to do

Comment: @GLOIERTECH. the concept is this, i have a datagrid, i populated it with different columns from different tables using inner join.

i need to do is.. a insert command. when i add data on the datagrid columns. it will add records or update records on the database

Comment: @ivandinglasan can you show us your code for datagrid?

Comment: @AshReva this is my code to populate my datagrid.
[code]     Dim Command As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand
        Command.Connection = sqlconn
        Command.CommandText = "OfficeEquipmentProfile"
        Command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure

        Dim sAdapter As SqlDataAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter(Command)

        Dim DataSet As DataSet = New DataSet(Command.CommandText)

        sAdapter.Fill(DataSet)
        DataGrid1.DataSource = DataSet.Tables(0)
[/code]

Answer (score 0):

Try this out.,

```
sqlConnection conn = new sqlConnection("Connection String");
conn.Open();

        sqlCommand command = new sqlCommand("Functionname", conn);
        command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
....
....
....
....
```